# Specifying a logback config file via maven command in jenkinsFile

Tags: java, powershell, maven, logback, jenkins-groovy

I use a custom logback.xml to configure logging.  Usually I pass it in via the logging.config property in  application.properties to the spring application, however I now need to specify a path to it so it can be picked up by a non-spring mvn module.

This command works fine in my intelliJ  run configuration:

`verify "-Dlogback.configurationFile=${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/myPath/logback.xml" -f pom.xml`

I thought that transferring this to my jenkinsFile would be trivial:

```
withMaven(mavenSettingsConfig: 'nexus-maven-settings') {
    withNPM(npmrcConfig: 'nexus-npm-ro-settings') {
        powershell 'mvn verify "-Dlogback.configurationFile=${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/myPath/logback.xml" -f webApp/com.pilz.ie.s30.automation/pom.xml'  
    }
}
```

but my logbackfile isn't working. I suspect it is a powershell issue with the single quote, double quotes or the Env var, but for some reason the logback file just isn't being picked up.

Any help appreciated!